# command -Dkotest.tags="tagName" is not working

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotest

Kotest ver.

```
testImplementation(platform("io.kotest:kotest-bom:5.8.0"))
testImplementation("io.kotest.extensions:kotest-extensions-spring:1.1.3")
testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core")
testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-json-jvm")
testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-runner-junit5-jvm")
testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-framework-datatest")
testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-property")
```

I got a test class with custom tag BEAVER. When i try to run
`./gradlew test -Dkotest.tags="BEAVER"` all test are fired (even without the tag).
example `./gradle test -Dkotest.tags="Linux & !Database"` returns error `zsh: event not found: Database` (MacOS)

```
object BEAVER: Tag()
class TagPlaygroundTest: StringSpec({
tags(BEAVER)

    "should pass with tag".config(tags = setOf(BEAVER)) {
        3 shouldBe 3
    }
    "should fail with tag".config(tags = setOf(BEAVER)) {
        3 shouldBe 4
    }
})
```

I want to run only tagged tests by using either ./gradlew or custom gradle tasks

Answer (score 1):

The reason why that doesn't work is that `-D` properties are supplied to `gradle`/`gradlew` and Gradle doesn't know it has to propagate them to Kotest. You need to change your `build.gradle` or `build.gradle.kts` file for Gradle to forward those properties to Kotest.

From the [Kotest documentation](https://kotest.io/docs/framework/tags.html#gradle):

> Special attention is needed in your gradle configuration
>
> To use System Properties (`-Dx=y`), your gradle must be configured to
> propagate them to the test executors, and an extra configuration must
> be added to your tests:
>
> Groovy:
>
> ```
> test {
>     //... Other configurations ...
>     systemProperties = System.properties
> }
> ```
>
> Kotlin Gradle DSL:
>
> ```
> val test by tasks.getting(Test::class) {
>     // ... Other configurations ...
>     systemProperties = System.getProperties().asIterable().associate {
>         it.key.toString() to it.value
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This will guarantee that the system property is correctly read by the
> JVM.